# How to add buttons into the TabbedPage above the Tabs

Tags: xamarin.forms

Is this possible to create ? I need to add 2 buttons above the tabs as below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<TabbedPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"          
    xmlns:local ="clr-namespace:SembIWIS.View"  
       x:Class="myApp.MainPage">

  <local:ProductPage>
  </local:ProductPage>

  <local:ServicePage>
  </local:ServicePage>

</TabbedPage>

How to add two buttons in the TabbedPage, so It will look like :

 |----------------------|
 | TabbedPage           |
 |----------------------|
 |                      |
 |  btn1        btn2    |
 |                      |
 |----------------------|
 | Tab1 | tab2 | tab3 ..|
 |----------------------|
 |                      |
 |                      |
 |                      | 
 ------------------------
```

Comment: Have you got any solution for this? I've to achieve the same in current requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done. You can use either a simple `Grid` structure or it can also be done with `StackLayouts` using `VerticalOptions = EndAndExpand`. This is the `Grid` version:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Grid.Row="0">
        // Normal content
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <Button Grid.Column="0" Text="Button 1" />
        <Button Grid.Column="1" Text="Button 2" />
    </Grid>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Where to place the Grid-tag? Above the first  Tab (ProductPage) ? ProductPage is a Normal XAML page.

Comment: It should go inside each page that needs this. If you want to make it a part of a tabbed page you will need to look into a custom renderer to override the default TabbedPage with your own implementation.

Comment: I need the button outside the Tabs. How to do it? what custom renderer to use. Can you guide me.

Comment: There is no cut–and–dried answer for this. It is a completely custom implementation depending on your requirements. Read up on Custom Renderers for Xamarin Forms at https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/application-fundamentals/custom-renderer/